# unmask encrypted field salesforce in email templates

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

I need to send an email to user with encrypted field unmasked. Is it possible?
I am using custom component and inside email template to fill in the data.
What i see is **** the masked value for the field.

Thanks.

Comment: No it is not. Sf will always mask the field in emails regardless of user permission

Comment: Eric thanks for your knowledge sharing is their any workaround?